# MySQL closest values order by count

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table:

```
name            count
Name 1          1
Name 2          1 
Name 3          1
Name 4          1
Name 5          2
Name 6          2
```

If I select Name 2 (count = 1), how do I select the next and previous item (Name 3, Name 1)? After all values are the same.

How to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you want a single query for this??

Comment: have a look at my answer below. may be this is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single query then I think this might be the query you are loooking for.

```
 select * from table where coun=(select coun from table where name='name1') 
and name!='name1'
```

I just rename count column to coun as count is an agg. function in mysql.
hope it works for you..